# Importing from .pyx file in google colab

Tags: import, jupyter, google-colaboratory, cython

I am trying to import from a .pyx file in google colab but I get the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'filename'`

My current code is:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
import sys
sys.path.append('/content/drive/My Drive/desiredPath')
from desiredModule import desiredClass
```

Any help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly import pyx files, they must be compiled using Cython.

See the [cython docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html) on how to build a cython-based project.